# What is the minimum number of "cases" for minority class to perform logistic regression?

Tags: regression, logistic, binomial-distribution, unbalanced-classes

I have 6 out of 167 cases of cancer in the dependent variable. I would evaluate if three independent variables predicted the cancer. Are 6 cases enough? Is there a rule to determine this? Is there difference if the indipendent variables is nominal or numeric?

Comment: What does "enough" mean?  If I were to say "enough" then I would personally say "given prevalence x, how many samples do I need for the Jeffreys prior on the rate to be within the range x-r to x+r.  Here is what a decent tool gives for your samples.  (http://epitools.ausvet.com.au/content.php?page=CIProportion&SampleSize=167&Positive=6&Conf=0.95&Digits=5)

Comment: 6 "Yes"s and 3 DVs will almost certainly produce complete separation in the data (which often manifests as huge coefficient estimates and standard errors). The rule of thumb usually says 5 or 10 cases per DV (depending on who you ask).

Comment: What do you mean by "6 out of 167"? Is is that 6 patients had cancer diagnosed ?

Comment: Related: http://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/26016/sample-size-for-logistic-regression

Answer (score 1):

I think there is no minimal number of "cases" to perform logistic regression (well at least you need to have 2 classes.).

The only downside is that, if you have a very imbalanced data, you may model minority poorly.

Also you may get some warnings from `R`, `glm`, if you have perfect separably data, so you may consider adding regularization.

[Regularization methods for logistic regression](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/228763/regularization-methods-for-logistic-regression)