# What is the equivalent in R of scikit-learn's `LogisticRegression` with `penalty="l2"`

Tags: r, logistic, scikit-learn

How do I implement in R the equivalent of

```
lr = LogisticRegression(penalty='l2')
lr.fit(X, y)
```

in R?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Your question is how to run L2 regularized logistic regression in R.

My another detailed answer can be found here. [Regularization methods for logistic regression](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/228763/regularization-methods-for-logistic-regression/228785#228785)

For implementation, there are more than one way of doing this.

- Method 1, use `glmnet(data,label,family="binomial", alpha=0, lambda=1)`, Details can be found in [glmnet manual](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/glmnet/glmnet.pdf), check page 9.
- Method 2
  Use `LiblineaR(data,label, type=0)` or `LiblineaR(data,label, type=7)`. Details can be found [LiblineaR manual](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/LiblineaR/LiblineaR.pdf) page 4. Both are L2-regularized logistic regression, one primal and one dual.
- Mehtod 3, manual implementation.

Here are code for the regularized logistic loss and it's gradient. We can use an optimization toolbox (such as BFGS) to optimize.

```
rm(list=ls())
set.seed(0)
library(mlbench)

d=mlbench.2dnormals(100,2)
x=d$x
y=ifelse(d$classes==1,1,0)
lambda=1


logistic_loss <- function(w){
  p=plogis(x %*% w)
  L=-y*log(p)-(1-y)*log(1-p)
  LwR2=sum(L)+lambda*t(w) %*% w
  return(c(LwR2))
}

logistic_loss_gr <- function(w){
  p=plogis(x %*% w)
  v=t(x) %*% (p - y)
    return(c(v)+2*lambda*w)
}

optim(runif(2),logistic_loss,logistic_loss_gr,method="BFGS")
```